# How to make a GitHub App ask for permissions per installation?

Tags: github, github-api, github-app

I have written a GitHub app that requests permissions for all repository contents.

The app basically reads a spec file that I created in order to do some custom logic.

The spec file can be located in any folder that the installer wants and therefore I ask for the elevated permissions.

For security reasons, I need the Github App to only have permissions to the specific file and not the entire repository contents.

Let's say I have 2 installations:

- Installation one will request permissions just to `some/path/to/folder/service.yml`
- Installation two will request permissions just to `service.yml`

I couldn't find any way to do so, not in the api of the installer, and not at the GitHub app level.

I thought about some workarounds using symlinks but it does not satisfy the requirement.